# WCF - when should i use netTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

i usually use HTTP binding at my services.
i read that net.tcp Binding works faster, however i am not quite sure on when should i use it?
what is the best practice,
are there any drawbacks?

thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx

Comment: It does work faster, net tcp is the basic one - "closest to the metal". I think it depends in your use case. Secured ? Inter process in single or multi machine, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSDN page for [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx#remarksToggle) says it best

> The default configuration for the NetTcpBinding is faster than the configuration provided by the WSHttpBinding, but it is intended only for WCF-to-WCF communication.

So NetTcpBinding is good to use when you have a .NET WCF client and a .NET WCF server, however if you need to support clients that are not written in .NET WCF (for example you are publishing a public service and you don't know what language the client will be written in) then you need to use a HttpBinding instead.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) has a good quick summary of each type of binding and when they should be used.

> - **BasicHttpBinding** - A binding that is suitable for communicating with WS-Basic Profile conformant Web services, for example, ASP.NET
>     Web services (ASMX)-based services. This binding uses HTTP as the
>     transport and text/XML as the default message encoding.
> - **WSHttpBinding** - A secure and interoperable binding that is suitable for non-duplex service contracts.
> - **WS2007HttpBinding** - A secure and interoperable binding that provides support for the correct versions of the Security,
>     ReliableSession, and TransactionFlow binding elements.
> - **WSDualHttpBinding** - A secure and interoperable binding that is suitable for duplex service contracts or communication through SOAP
>     intermediaries.
> - **WSFederationHttpBinding** - A secure and interoperable binding that supports the WS-Federation protocol, enabling organizations that
>     are in a federation to efficiently authenticate and authorize users.
> - **WS2007FederationHttpBinding** - A secure and interoperable binding that derives from WS2007HttpBinding and supports federated
>     security.
> - **NetTcpBinding** - A secure and optimized binding suitable for cross-machine communication between WCF applications.
> - **NetNamedPipeBinding** - A secure, reliable, optimized binding that is suitable for on-machine communication between WCF
>     applications.
> - **NetMsmqBinding** - A queued binding that is suitable for cross-machine communication between WCF applications.
> - **NetPeerTcpBinding** - A binding that enables secure, multi-machine communication.
> - **WebHttpBinding** - A binding used to configure endpoints for WCF Web services that are exposed through HTTP requests instead of SOAP
>     messages.
> - **MsmqIntegrationBinding** - A binding that is suitable for cross-machine communication between a WCF application and existing
>     Message Queuing (also known as MSMQ) applications.